# it is possible to update my app on play store and app Store with different app with same design and purpose?

Tags: flutter, dart, app-store, google-play-console

I have an flutter app already launching on play store and apple store but it so bad for Editing  because there architecture is bad
what I want is  recreate its app from zero
then updating my old app to new app, it is possible?

**NOTE: old app have a key**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think everything comes down to bundle identifier: com.example.something.

you can test with simple hello app and see.